Does HTTP protocol require the underlying transport protocol to be connection-based?
I'm studying Mozilla's HTTP protocol reference and I don't understand what the following part means:

A connection is controlled at the transport layer, and therefore fundamentally out of scope for HTTP. HTTP doesn't require the underlying transport protocol to be connection-based; it only requires it to be reliable, or not lose messages (at minimum, presenting an error in such cases). Among the two most common transport protocols on the Internet, TCP is reliable and UDP isn't. HTTP therefore relies on the TCP standard, which is connection-based.

There are some statements that seem to be contradictory:

HTTP doesn't require the underlying transport protocol to be connection based.
HTTP relies on the TCP standard, which is connection-based.

My question:
Is there ever a situation where we don't need to establish a connection to the server over transport protocol before we send a HTTP (or any application level) request, and is that what connection-based means?

Why are the statements contradictory? It doesn't use TCP because of its connection-based nature. It uses TCP because of the reliability.

@DanielB If the connection-based aspect is irrelevant, why is it mentioned at all?

At the time of HTTP being created, TCP was the major universally available transport protocol for the Internet that provided the necessary properties – using UDP was possible but would've required HTTP itself to provide reliability, RDP (as in Reliable Data Protocol) saw little adoption, SCTP hadn't been invented yet, etc., whereas TCP was available on almost every system that had an IP implementation1.
So TCP was the natural choice for HTTP servers and clients to use, and since all implementations need to agree on the transport, in practice HTTP relies on TCP for interoperability.
However, HTTP explicitly does not keep any per-connection state – two HTTP requests will behave the same whether they came through a single TCP connection or through different connections – therefore it does not rely on the "connection-based" property of TCP; it relies on TCP for its other properties only.
(Recently though, many implementations have started supporting QUIC as an alternative transport. It is sort-of but not exactly "HTTP over UDP", as QUIC really sits on almost the same level as TCP in terms of properties it provides to the application protocol.)

Is there ever a situation where we don't need to establish a connection to the server over transport protocol before we send a HTTP (or any application level) request

HTTP can work this way; as mentioned, it doesn't keep any connection-level state, so it can work over transports that don't have explicit connect or disconnect. (I've seen HTTP over UDP, HTTP over D-Bus, etc.)
There are plenty of application-level protocols that do not use a connection-based transport; DNS and NTP are two of the most common examples, both of which are based around one-shot request exchanges without any explicit connect/disconnect operations. (DNS can and often does use TCP, but UDP remains its default transport for most operations.)

1 (In fact the reason there was no "IPv2" or "IPv3" was because it was known as "TCPv2" and "TCPv3" before being split into the two TCP/IP layers for version 4...)

Great answer as always. I need to study more what connection-based means. I found it's a synonym for connection-oriented.

I prefer to think of QUIC as simply another protocol at the Transport Layer next to TCP, UDP, RDP, SCTP, DCCP, etc. The fact that it actually uses another Transport Layer protocol (UDP) is simply a hack to make it compatible with the vast array of "middleboxes" on the Internet (stateful L4 firewalls, L4 routers, IDS, etc.) that only know about UDP and TCP and are not easily upgraded or replaced. If it were easy to replace those, it would be built directly on top of IP, like all the other protocols. That's precisely the problem DCCP, SCTP and RDP have with becoming popular.
